# Getting Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel

This VBA code verifies calculated cells. If the value is over $500.00 or has #N/A, then it should color the entire row and bold font.

But I keep getting this `Type Mismatch` error:

```
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For lngCounter = 3 To Lastrow
    With Cells(lngCounter, "J")
        If .Value >= 500 Or IsError(Cells) Then
            Cells(lngCounter, "I").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Cells(lngCounter, "J").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Rows(lngCounter).Font.Bold = True

        Else

        End If
    End With
Next lngCounter
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: or maybe just IsError(.value)?

Comment: I see it. The error is when you're doing the comparison to `.Value` if it is an error. I'll work up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is probably raising the error:

`If .Value >= 500 Or IsError(Cells) Then`

There are two errors in that line.  `Cells` is nothing in your code. you would need like `Cells(lngCounter, "J")` etc.

Also, if that cell contains an error value, you will get the Mismatch error when trying to evaluate the first half of that statment, because `#N/A` or `#DIV0!` etc are not numeric values and therefore present a type Mismatch when used with numeric operators like `>=`.

Use some more variables, and fine-tune the code a bit. Try this (untested):

```
Sub Test()
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim myCell as Range

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For lngCounter = 3 To Lastrow
    Set myCell = Cells(lngCounter, "J")
    With myCell
        If IsError(.Value) Then
            FormatThis myCell
        ElseIf .Value >= 500 Then
            FormatThis myCell
        End If
    End With
Next lngCounter
End Sub
Sub FormatThis(cl as Range)
    'receives a cell in column J, use the OFFSET and RESIZE methods
    ' to return a range of cells in columns I & J to format color.
    cl.Offset(0,-1).Resize(1,2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Rows(cl.Row).Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey David, the Colored cells need to be in column I and J. How can i fix that?

Comment: Sweet. Awesome. everything works awesome now. Thanks again! i have long ways to go to be good in VBA. -_-

Comment: OK it sounds like you noticed my revision :) glad it is working for you!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be VBA? You could apply this conditional format formula to rows 3:65536

```
=AND(OR($J3>=500,ISNA($J3)),$J3<>"")
```

Comment: +1 and then use that calculated value in a conditional format.. except I wouldn't put it in $3:$65536 but only in the used range.

Comment: ya this had to be VBA

Answer (score 1):

You must always test for the error **first**:

```
Sub dural()
For Each r In Selection
    If IsError(r.Value) Then
        MsgBox r.Text
    Else
        If r.Value > 100 Then
            MsgBox r.Value
        End If
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```